# Return an else value when using recur

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure, and doing my best to forget all my previous experience with more procedural languages (java, ruby, swift) and embrace Clojure for what it is. I am actually really enjoying the way it makes me think differently -- however, I have come up against a pattern that I just can't seem to figure out. The easiest way to illustrate, is with some code:

```
(defn char-to-int [c] (Integer/valueOf (str c)))

(defn digits-dont-decrease? [str]
  (let [digits (map char-to-int (seq str)) i 0]
    (when (< i 5)
      (if (> (nth digits i) (nth digits (+ i 1)))
        false
        (recur (inc i))))))

(def result (digits-dont-decrease? "112233"))

(if (= true result)
  (println "fit rules")
  (println "doesn't fit rules"))
```

The input is a 6 digit number as a string, and I am simply attempting to make sure that each digit from left to right is >= the previous digit. I want to return false if it doesn't, and true if it does. The false situation works great -- however, given that `recur` needs to be the last thing in the function (as far as I can tell), how do I return true. As it is, when the condition is satisfied, I get an illegal argument exception:

```
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at clojure.exercise.two/digits-dont-decrease? (four:20).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

How should I be thinking about this? I assume my past training is getting in my mental way.

Comment: You missed `recur` will call the function, replace `let` with `loop` and `(recur digits (inc i))`, `(loop [digits (map ...) i 0] (if (< i (count digits) (if (...) false (recur digits (inc c)) true)`

Comment: SPOILER: https://github.com/transducer/adventofcode/blob/master/src/adventofcode/2019/day4.clj#L26 ;). So turn the string into digits and then `apply <=`

Comment: thanks to everyone who answered, they're all great answers that taught me something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nothing but

```clj
(apply <= "112233")
```

Reason: string is a sequence of character and comparison operator works on character.

```clj
(->> "0123456789" (mapcat #(repeat 1000 %)) (apply str) (def loooong))

(count loooong)
10000

(time (apply <= loooong))
"Elapsed time: 21.006625 msecs"
true

(->> "9123456789" (mapcat #(repeat 1000 %)) (apply str) (def bad-loooong))

(count bad-loooong)
10000

(time (apply <= bad-loooong))
"Elapsed time: 2.581750 msecs"
false
```

(above runs on my iPhone)

Answer (score 4):

This is not answering your question, but also shows an alternative.  While the `(apply < ...)` approach over the whole string is very elegant for small strings (it is eager), you can use `every?` for an short-circuiting approach.  E.g.:

```clj
user=> (defn nr-seq [s] (map #(Integer/parseInt (str %)) s))
#'user/nr-seq
user=> (every? (partial apply <=) (partition 2 1 (nr-seq "123")))
true
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't really need loop/recur.  Just use the built-in nature of `<=` like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def true-samples
  ["123"
   "112233"
   "13"])

(def false-samples
  ["10"
   "12324"])

(defn char->int
  [char-or-str]
  (let [str-val (str char-or-str)] ; coerce any chars to len-1 strings
    (assert (= 1 (count str-val)))
    (Integer/parseInt str-val)))


(dotest
  (is= 5 (char->int "5"))
  (is= 5 (char->int \5))

  (is= [1 2 3] (mapv char->int "123"))

  ; this shows what we are going for
  (is (<= 1 1 2 2 3 3))
  (isnt (<= 1 1 2 1 3 3))
```

and now test the char sequences:

```
  ;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; using built-in `<=` function
  (doseq [true-samp true-samples]
    (let [digit-vals (mapv char->int true-samp)]
      (is (apply <= digit-vals))))

  (doseq [false-samp false-samples]
    (let [digit-vals (mapv char->int false-samp)]
      (isnt (apply <= digit-vals))))
```

if you want to write your own, you can like so:

```
(defn increasing-equal-seq?
  "Returns true iff sequence is non-decreasing"
  [coll]
  (when (< (count coll) 2)
    (throw (ex-info "coll must have at least 2 vals" {:coll coll})))
  (loop [prev      (first coll)
         remaining (rest coll)]
    (if (empty? remaining)
      true
      (let [curr           (first remaining)
            prev-next      curr
            remaining-next (rest remaining)]
        (if (<= prev curr)
          (recur prev-next remaining-next)
          false)))))

  ;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; using home-grown loop/recur
  (doseq [true-samp true-samples]
    (let [digit-vals (mapv char->int true-samp)]
      (is (increasing-equal-seq? digit-vals))))

  (doseq [false-samp false-samples]
    (let [digit-vals (mapv char->int false-samp)]
      (isnt (increasing-equal-seq? digit-vals))))
)
```

with result

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 15 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 23:36:17.096 (run time: 0.028s)
```

Comment: `apply` is very nice - but only for small strings - it is eager.  Also this is quite some wall of code to show `(apply <= ...)`.

Comment: sorry, you are right.  i must have trailed off in the middle ;)

Answer (score 1):

You an use `loop` with `recur`.
Assuming you require following input v/s output -

- "543221" => false
- "54321" => false
- "12345" => true
- "123345" => true

Following function can help

```
;; Assuming char-to-int is defined by you before as per the question

(defn digits-dont-decrease?
  [strng]
  (let [digits (map char-to-int (seq strng))]
    (loop [;;the bindings in loop act as initial state
      decreases true
      i (- (count digits) 2)]
      (let [decreases (and decreases (>= (nth digits (+ i 1)) (nth digits i)))]
        (if (or (< i 1) (not decreases))
          decreases
          (recur decreases (dec i)))))))
```

This should work for numeric string of any length.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you were looking for something else :).

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn non-decreasing? [str]
  (every?
   identity
   (map
    (fn [a b]
      (<= (int a) (int b)))
    (seq str)
    (rest str))))

(defn non-decreasing-loop? [str]
  (loop [a (seq str) b (rest str)]
    (if-not (seq b)
      true
      (if (<= (int (first a)) (int (first b)))
        (recur (rest a) (rest b))
        false))))

(non-decreasing? "112334589")
(non-decreasing? "112324589")
(non-decreasing-loop? "112334589")
(non-decreasing-loop? "112324589")
```

Comment: Please explain you solution a little bit! That makes it much easier and faster to understand what you are doing and why.